# Adding Anchor CMS blog section to existing html/bootstrap website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor-cms

I have successfully installed and ran the Anchor CMS and now I am trying to add it to my existing company website. I have a navbar menu and would like to link the Blog posts section, so that when the menu item is clicked, the user is redirected.

I have tried the standard linking but it doesn't work in that case.I have tried multiple version of the href link including posts.php. I have moved the Anchor CMS file to the root directory of the website. I am using local XAMPP server.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#story">Our Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#facts">Facts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#products">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a  href="http://localhost/anchor-cms-0.12.7/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click the Blog menu item nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for your help, I only have beginners knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround could be to add a `target="_blank"` to the link and open it in a new tab. So it should say `<li><a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/anchor-cms-0.12.7/">Blog</a></li>`.

It is possible that some JavaScript is blocking the default action of the link. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050095/a-link-not-working-by-clicking-only-work-by-open-link-in-new-tab-command) if some of the answers help yo