# <a> tag is not opening the linked page rather refreshes and stays on itself on clicking

Tags: html, css, visual-web-developer

HTML Code:

```html
<a href="work-exp.php" class="next-container"><button class="next">Next</button></a>
```

If I click on the button, it supposed to take me on that link but this is not redirecting to that page and stays on the same page but if I open the link in a new tab then this is opening the linked page

Comment: can you add some of the HTML code?

Comment: <a href="home.php" class="next-container"><button class="next">Next</button></a>                                                                                                                               this was my code

Comment: Possible duplicate [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050095/a-link-not-working-by-clicking-only-work-by-open-link-in-new-tab-command)

Comment: @DebankarRoy what server are you using?

Comment: @AdityaThakur Apache

Comment: Well  your code seems to work with a full URL path, so it should work with a local file in the same directory. It's indeed strange if the link opens the file in a new tab, but not in the same tab.

Comment: **Links can't contain buttons** and **Buttons can't contain links**. Pick one or the other, *not both*.

Comment: Your class `next-container` might be preventing the default action. Check your script.