# bootstrap nav bar links do not work when resizing window

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have created a UI which uses bootstrap 4 and I've implemented a sticky nav bar but the links do not consistanly navigate the user when displayed on smaller screens (when the hamburger menu is used).

To reproduce the bug (screen width: 760):

- load page
- open hamburger menu
- click link (sucessfully navigates)
- click home button
- open hamburger menu
- click link (nothing happens)

In full screen mode I can click a link and sucessfully navigate as many times as I want.

I have read other questions around this issue and they talk about the z-index, however I tried that but it does not resolve my problem.

After several hours of looking at this issue I have come to an end

Why is this happening?

NB:
I have not yet posted any code from my nav bar or the associated cssc because I really have no idea where the problem is. If there is any advice that can help me narrow that down I will add the relevant piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer in case anyone else is suffering the same pain I did.

I finally resolved this issue thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050095/a-link-not-working-by-clicking-only-work-by-open-link-in-new-tab-command). Ultimatly the answer was that a class was added in my link that had a JS event which prevented default actions.

```
function active_dropdown() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('.menu li.submenu > a').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find('ul').first().toggle(700);
            $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide(700);
        });
    }
}
```

I was able to track it down by inspecting the element and viewing the attached event (as explained in the link posted above)

[image]