# How to open URL in a new tab on which website allow open another link via button click only

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

When I browse a webiste I want to open a link `myURL` that's showed in href as below script of HTML of web app.

```html
<a href="myURL" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <li class="abc">
        <div class="acds"
            tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(237, 238, 239);"><img
                alt="ReShark"
                src="data:image/png;base64,qư/oQDD/oADD/oADD/nwCbdFr/oAD/oABBqG/hTX/oQD/w+PhqCGR/pT/VMUSW5xPgYXWajnAtl1YuxaPqc="
                style="width: 24px; height: 24px; margin: 10px;">
            <div class="XY"><span
                    class="MY">NAME</span>
                <p
                    class="MHY">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                    <p class="MFEy">07:17
                        13/02/2023</p>
                    <p class="DS">+ 123</p>
                </div>
                </p>
            </div><span class="St"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
```

This web app allow to load new page via button click only and redirect to `myURL` on address bar. If I put `myURL` on address bar of new tab It is redirected to home page instead of open that URL

I find out from [<a> link not working by clicking, only work by "Open link in new tab" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050095/a-link-not-working-by-clicking-only-work-by-open-link-in-new-tab-command).
However I don't know where to see function prevent go that URL on Development Tool of Chorme
I expect to use selenium to open that `myURL` in a new tab

Comment: Are there cookies? Maybe you need to copy the cookies from the current window and set some cookies in the new window before you navigate to 'myURL'? Hard to say without being able to look at the app code. If that doesn't work there is likely some kind of flag in the app code that flips when the button is clicked.

Comment: @tehbeardedone I paste override `myURL` on adress bar of existing window. However It is not open eventually. Homepage is again opened instead of `myURL`